# How to change the min-height of one div as per height of other div

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css

We have two div's in which one div contain only contents and other one have bootstraps collapse with content . So here what happen is whe we click the collapisable elemnt 
it will open and the height of it's parent increase automatically. We have many collapisable div.

> Now how we can set the div 1 height is same as  with div 2 height ?. If div 2 height increase then div 1 height also need to increase.

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Accordion Example</h2>
  <p><strong>Note:</strong> The <strong>data-parent</strong> attribute makes sure that all collapsible elements under the specified parent will be closed when one of the collapsible item is shown.</p>

  <div class="col-sm-6 div1">

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>

  <div class='col-sm-6 div2'>
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Collapsible Group 1</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
          <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Collapsible Group 2</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Collapsible Group 3</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please help

Comment: Please send fiddle.

Comment: You want all of the divs to have same height? or same min-height?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. From your description (of wanting all the divs to be the same height) it sounds like the whole point of the collapsible plugin is redundant

Comment: Where is your custom stylesheet? Do you have background applied on `div1` that you wants to sync with `div2` height?

Comment: I understand what you're asking but I just can't think of a reason why ?? Why would you want to increase a div(`div1`)'s height which has no relation to `div2` whatsoever ? `div1`'s content are not changing at all when you use your collapsible. So wouldn't it just leave a HUGE gap between the two divs when you increase the height ??

Comment: Your question was a bit confusing. You just wanted to keep the heights of div1 same as div2 right? Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".div1").css({
  'height': ($(".div2").height() + 'px')
});

$('#accordion').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
  // do something…
  $(".div1").css({
    'height': ($(".div2").height() + 'px')
  });
})
```

A better way using Bootstrap's method

Check the code on : 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rWLQNg

Comment: you are correct .This thing i know .But here when click on Collapsible Group 1 then it will expand . SO div 2 height increase .But div1 height not increase.

Comment: Please check the codepan example that you give . In that also when user click collapisable group div2 height increasing , but code1 height is not increasing .

Comment: updated the fiddle. Also don't expect us to make everything ready for you. We are here to guide you in the right direction. :)

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this to match heights of elements with the same class.

```
function matchHeight(elem){
        var elemH = 0;
        $(elem).each(function(){
            elem.css('height', 'auto');
            if($(this).outerHeight() > elemH){
                elemH = $(this).outerHeight();
            }
        });
        $(elem).height(elemH + 'px');
    };
```

So on any event you could do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    matchHeight('.className');
});
```